# Convert a GUID into an integer Powershell?

Tags: integer, guid

I have a Webservice which tells me this is the function parameters..

```
    Public Function Create(ByVal Name As String, ByVal templateId As Integer)
```

The issue is the templateid is a GUID. if i pass this into the Function the function wont work as it needs to be an integer. I can def say the templateid is a GUID from a SQL database.

so how can i change that GUID into an integer so the function will accept it? is it possible?

all parse tests have come back as false meaning its not possible.

Comment: GUID is alpha numeric and hence you Can't convert it to an integer. Ex: 1xy2 - Can this be an integer ? No, the same applies to GUID as well.

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean this for instance? `51bcd3b9-a94b-45f0-a3f1-8194dca4ae7d`

Comment: How does this question pertain to PowerShell?

Comment: Good point @TrevorSullivan, I've removed the tag.

Comment: I am using powershell to call the webservice function. So i want to convert the GUID prior to running the function.

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan not quite correct. It is true that C#/PowerShell GUIDs are alphanumeric, but more specifically, they are *hexadecimal*. Meaning that they can be converted to integers. See the constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-guid-ctor(system-string)

Comment: Also see GUID.ToString() Method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-guid-tostring

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from the function definition that it's Visual Basic, in which the `Integer` type is a 32 bit signed integer. Even if it were a 64 bit unsigned integer, a `[guid]` is 128 bits, so its value will not fit into an `Integer`.

Comment: I am thinking this is going back to the vendor - I cannot pass an ID as an integer so the function must change

Comment: No longer an issue with .NET 7 and .NET 8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to "convert" a GUID into an integer, using conventional means. You could create some special algorithm that performs the conversion, according to your own specification, but there's no standard for this.

There are a couple of options that I see, without having more details about the scenario:

1. Modify the function to accept a GUID as a string
2. Modify the SQL Database to have unique identifiers as integers **and** GUIDs separately. (not ideal)

Comment: The function is hardcoded from the vendor i cannot change that. Again the SQL side is all hardcoded. I am confused as to why the function asks for an integer so i was hoping to 'trick' it with a convert

Comment: C#/PowerShell GUIDs are hexadecimal, so they can be converted to integer, but they have to be parsed. See the constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-guid-ctor(system-string)

Comment: Also see GUID.ToString() Method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-guid-tostring

Answer (score 0):

Both C# and PowerShell represent GUIDs as 128 bit hyphenated hexadecimal numbers.

It is important to highlight that they are hexadecimal numbers, because the other answers lead you to believe that they are just alphanumeric. The reason for this is that [the documentation on C# GUIDs does not explicitly say that they are](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-7.0), however, the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-guid-ctor(system-string)) and [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-guid-tostring) methods do.

Now, the second problem is that GUIDs are 128 bit. At the time that the other answers were written, .NET's largest integer values were 64 bit. [With .NET 7.0, that is no longer true - 128 bit integers are ***now supported***.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0#applies-to)

So, to answer your question, you can convert a GUID to an Int128 in PowerShell 7.0 by removing the hyphens and parsing it like so:

```
# C# API:
# static long System.Int128.Parse(string s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style)
#
# Relevant NumberStyles Value in PowerShell:
# [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::HexNumber = 515

[Int128]::Parse( ((New-Guid) -replace "-", ""), 515 )
```